Display on the Primary Category in the WordPress Permalink
I am working on a recipe blog which uses the permalink slug (Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks) as
domain/%category%/%postname%/

this blog has multiple (8+) child-categories under almost all every parent category. A smoothie post was made under the "Courses" (parent category) > "Juices/Smoothies" (Child Category), also the primary category is set to "Juices/Smoothies" When the post is publish it's using the permalink as:
domain/courses/juice-smoothies/smoothie-recipe

What I am trying to achieve is a link with only the child category and drop the parent category from the URL, like:
domain/juice-smoothies/smoothie-recipe

I tried checking/unchecking the courses but it didn't work tried only selecting the "Juices/Smoothies" but that didn't work either.
Looking forward to a solution since I can't really find this on the WP forum as well but too much similar and confusing information.
PS: this blog is using the RankMath SEO plugin but the URL structure are not modified using this plugin. I will be happy to provide any additional information required to achivee the goal here and I appreciate all the responses in advance :)

Check this demo : https://therichpost.com/how-to-display-primary-category-in-the-wordpress-permalink/

I would recommend installing the Yoast SEO plugin if you already don't have it. It adds the feature of a primary category (see bottom of screenshot).

You'd be able to set "Juice/Smoothies" as the primary category of the post. You'd then have to retrieve it using something like this:
function get_primary_category($post_id) {
  $primary_category_id = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', true);
  $primary_category = get_category($primary_category_id);

  return $primary_category;
}


I am using RankMath and already have done a lot of on-page optimization and can't afford to change the SEO plugin plus Yoast adds a huge bloat of useless functions that one never uses. So unfortunately Yoast isn't an option for this particular blog

It looks like Rank Math has a similar option - https://rankmath.com/kb/how-to-choose-a-primary-category/

RankMath does NOT offer an option to set Child Category within the permalink structure. All it does it set the Category base which does NOT solve this issue :) Have already applied and went through that link before posting this question here
